# Button click doesn't stop triggering

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a button in an ASP page that I click to save some data to an SQL server. It works as intended, except that any time the page reloads (when doing other things) it triggers the submission again of that button. The result is duplicate records in the database. I realize I could probably validate for duplicates, but my concern is that if the button is still triggering a click on each refresh that it's consuming resources for no reason.

On each refresh it says "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

I have searched the rest of the codebehind, HTML, and javascript file for any references to button11 and there are none. I'm stumped why it keeps triggering.

The button's HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="button11" runat="server" OnClick="Button11_Click" />
```

Codebehind:

```
    protected void Button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var update = hfptstate.Value;
    string fname = fnamebox.Text;
    string lname = lnamebox.Text;
    string sex = sexbox.Text;
    string combname = fname + " " + lname;
    string init = null;
    string str = combname;
    str.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().ForEach(i => init += i[0]);
    init += "_";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int id = rnd.Next(1, 10000);
    string initid = init + id;
    string phone = phonebox.Text;
    string color = colorbox.Text;
    string age = agebox.Text;
    string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd yyyy h:mmtt");

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Public\\public website\\slDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    if (statuslabel.InnerText == "Adding New Record")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into precordTable VALUES ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + combname + "', '" + initid + "' , '' , '" + sex + "', '" + phone + "', '" + color + "', '" + age + "', '" + datetime + "', '','')", con);
    }
    else if (statuslabel.InnerText == "Editing Existing Record")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("update precordTable set fname='" + fname + "', lname='" + lname + "', name='" + combname + "' , sex='" + sex + "', phone='" + phone + "', color='" + color + "', age='" + age + "' where initid='" + update + "';", con);
    }
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    statuslabel.InnerText = "Adding New Record";
    fnamebox.Text = "";
    lnamebox.Text = "";
    sexbox.Text = "";
    phonebox.Text = "";
    colorbox.Text = "";
    agebox.Text = "";

}
```

Edit: I also know about bobby drop tables. It's not a concern for this specific implementation.

Edit 2: I forgot to mention that just clicking the refresh button is enough to add duplicate records, and it doesn't even give the form submission warning ("To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.")

Comment: It sounds like you are somehow triggering the button click event in the Page_Load event.  Can you post whatever code you have in that event?

Comment: I commented everything out of it and it still happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default browser behavior. 
The last request you sent to the server was the POST request of the button.
Refreshing the browser will redo the last request, which will invoke the button click event.

Below link helps you solve the issue:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319955/How-to-prevent-Re-Post-action-caused-by-pressing-b

Answer (score 1):

It has been a lukewarm hot while since I have worked on an ASP.NET WebForms (your code is webforms, right?) project, and I am not totally sure there isn't any info about your situation that would make a difference in trying to understand what might be wrong, but I seem to recall something catchy about the page lifecycle in that the data that is set to the session variables data is not reset to a default value or by later code event methods later in the page life cycle when it has been persisted.  You should be able to check that by debugging the code in those different events.  If it is not exactly that problem, it might likely be something else catchy about the page life cycle not sessioning how you might expect it to.

One good reference is straight from the source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx, I think that page has improved significantly since the early days of WebForms.  HTH